# {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a database first MVC4 application of VS2012 Express  but when run the application given the error:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"}

please help me anyone.

Comment: Do you have Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5.0.0 as a part of your project?

Answer (score 1):

In the View > Other > Package Manager Console write:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comment: I have follow your step but its give same error

Comment: After typing and hitting the enter on the console what was typed?

Comment: I type Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json and press enter

Comment: @user3922346 - is Newtonsoft.Json DLL copied to your bin folder?

Comment: Could you submit output string after installing the package?

Comment: Remove the entry from ur config that specifies that version or point it t ok the right version :-o

Comment: Thanks after delete Newtonsoft.Json DLL from bin folder it works done.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is also to use the `bindingRedirect` in your App.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Please note, that the 'oldVerion' and 'newVerison' might not be completely correct, because I don't know which versions are actually used in your case. Basically you are telling the runtime, to use the version described in 'newVersion' no matter which version is found (provided that the found version is in the 'oldVersion' range)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this sort of error myself. I bet you are using another assembly that is referencing a specific version of Newtonsoft.Json. It is not that the assembly is missing, it is just not the correct version of the assembly to satisfy the third party assembly's reference. If you are directly referencing the assembly yourself, downgrade your reference to the same version as the third party library or upgrade the third party library so that its reference has the same version as yours.

Comment: Or add the latest version using the package manager, which will add the proper redirections. Or add the proper assembly redirections by hand. No need to downgrade

Comment: Assuming there are no breaking changes...

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this error gives when there is different version of dll is being reference. If this is the case then use bindingRedirect mentioned by Andro.